# Adobe Air 1.5.2 and Flash Builder

Tags: air, gumbo

Recently I'm working on some air stuff, and I am using Flash Builder and latest Nightly build SDK in order to compile my application ( I even used stable version before this stage ), but when ever I export the final air file from the Flash Builder, the air file giving me this error message :

**The application could not be installed because the AIR file is damaged. Try obtaining a new AIR file from the application author.**

I wounder what's wrong about my file?! I even changed the namespace to other versions like 1.5.1 and 1.5 but none of them will do the trick! Any one has any idea?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try logging the application install it might give you more info and troubleshooting information - http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403123.html

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com